# Facebook Login - Magento extension

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

We have a Magento extension - EZLOGIN LITE for Facebook login.
Set everything up, but when you click 'F log in' still getting this: "Dear Customer! Allow this application to complete the login process".

Here is link: http://www.blubond.com/store/customer/account/login/

But 'F log in' is temporary removed because of this.

Anyone know what is it about?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is 'F log in' link the given site?

Comment: It is temporary removed, because of reason above. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have any Development server?

Comment: I have.

http://blubond.magentostaging.com/store/customer/account/login/

And there everything works. :(
Thank you.

Comment: I have answered and edited it, Kindly check it once.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for commenting back.

For me the development server's facebook login also not working fine.

Showing like this :

[image]

For which domain you have downloaded the extension, That will work for that domain only I think, So you download the extension again by giving the production server(http://www.blubond.com/) link from http://store.velanapps.com/products/magento/free-facebook-login-extension.

While creating facebook app also you have to give site url.
So create one more facebook app by giving the production server link(http://www.blubond.com/)
as given in this guide : http://velanapps.com/Ezlogin-Installation-Manual.pdf

Try by doing this. If then also it didn't work, I will help you out.

Cheers :-)

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for your time and answer. I do all this you write above in answer. Download brand new Magento extension, ordered with proper domain (www.blubond.com), install it, followed again all by Install manual. Facebook app also create new one, with also proper url... And again same message! :(